# Support for em-dash in Windows file paths using StgOpenStorage()

Tags: visual-c++, windows-7-x64, ole

I had a customer reporting problems with a file in a specific path. Debugging some old Windows code, I have found that the code in question that fails is a call to StgOpenStorage(). The path in question that fails has an em-dash. If I take this em-dash out by renaming the file, then the call to StgOpenStorage() succeeds.

So my question is this: is this a known limitation with this function? Are there likely to be other Windows SDK functions that fail with special characters like em-dash? I noticed there is a call to mbstowcs() prior to calling this function, which makes me wonder if the problem is due to the code-page mapping the em-dash character incorrectly. The wchar path looks okay in the Visual Studio debugger prior to the call, so it seems weird that the function would fail on a path that the system allows.

Comment: *"there is a call to mbstowcs() prior to calling this function"* - this is almost certainly the problem, it's probably converting to a different UNICODE character or failing to convert at all, and then `StgOpenStorage` can't find the file. What error code do you get when it fails? Is it `STG_E_FILENOTFOUND`?

Answer (score 1):

You were right Roger Rowland, it was due to the active locale prior to the call to mbstowcs(). I fixed this problem by calling:

```
setlocale( LC_ALL, "" );
```

Prior to the call to mbstowcs(). It looks like for some reason the "C" locale doesn't support em-dash, as if I set this instead it fails:

```
setlocale( LC_ALL, "C" );
```

My regional settings are set to English (Australia).

Cheers.